# How to find coordinates of cluster in k-means

Tags: cluster-analysis, k-means

I'm trying to use k-means clustering on a vector of type key-values. My question is, how do I set the coordinates of each element in the vector? Specifically the key-value pairs are strings-floats. I need this to find later the center of the cluster.

Comment: Does anyone know where I can find an implementation of k-means in c# so I can give it a look?
I know that I'll have to define each element in a 2-dimensional space (at least) but how can I do this? Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Clustering algorithms typically only classify vertices to clusters. What you are looking for is a cluster-rendering algorithm which given a cluster partition of a graph renders the graph for visualization in a suitable way. I would say keep your cluster algorithm and visualization algorithms separate. Force-directed layout is a good simple cluster visualization algorithm.

And, lastly, [here](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/cluster.html) is a link to an implementation and [another one](http://code.google.com/p/scipy-cluster/).

Answer (score 0):

K-means algorithms do generally compute centroids of clusters.  For instance, in R's implementation:

```
n.clin <- 10
n.pop <- 100
clinicdat <- data.frame( x=runif(n.clin), y=runif(n.clin) )
popdat <- data.frame( x=runif(n.pop), y=runif(n.pop), pop=sample(1:5000, n.pop) )
plot(popdat$y~popdat$x, col="grey")
points(clinicdat$y~clinicdat$x, col="red")
km <- kmeans( subset(popdat,select=c(x,y)), n.clin )
points( fitted(km, method="centers"), col="green" )
```

[image]